# I wan to know the logic of geodist() function in solr

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I wan to know the logic of geodist() function in solr as I am getting different distance on geodist() and while I am checking the same through google maps.

Comment: It's a basic haversine implementation: https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/c99af207c761ec34812ef1cc3054eb2804b7448b/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/function/distance/HaversineConstFunction.java  - It is expected that google maps will have a different value than what the haversine formula gives you. Any distance function will always be an approximation - it's just about which approximation you choose.

Comment: Got it thanks...Could you help for this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71419769/i-want-to-index-multivalue-daterange-in-solr

Answer (score 1):

The 'logic of geodist() function' is based on calculating the distance between 2 points of a sphere. The reason you are getting different distances with Google Maps is due to the fact that Google uses navigational distance - not point to point. Haversine (great-circle distances between two points on a sphere; lat,lon) is the default system used by Solr to calculate the distance between 2 points. Solr also supports other distance calculators such as Euclidean which is line distance.